# jaxb bindingx.xml "results in too many target nodes"

Tags: xpath, jaxb, xsd

I'm trying to make just one adapter for every type of element, so I created a bindings.xml file:

```
<jxb:bindings node="//xs:attribute[@type='Id']"
```

so, my intention is to address to every attribute of type "Id".
Problem is that xjc tells me "too many target nodes(3)" ... but it's just what I want!!

Answer (score 44):

Try to add multiple="true" attribute:

```
<jxb:bindings multiple="true" node="//xs:attribute[@type='Id']"
```

Comment: got the same problem, and `multiple="true"` gives: _unable to honor this property customization. It is attached to a wrong place, or its inconsistent with other bindings._

Comment: I added `multiple="true"`, but I am still getting the error message "too many target nodes".

Comment: Man if it's supported that simple... why didn't they just allow multiple nodes as default..? Tnx for the answer!

Answer (score 0):

I end up with a similar problem "too many target nodes(3)" however could not find any answer on any of the sites...Posting the solution which I found after lots of trail and error...Basic idea to solve "too many target nodes(3)" is to give complete XPATH of the node which is multiple in your XSD.

Below is my XSD:

```
<xs:schema attributeFormDefault="unqualified" elementFormDefault="qualified" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <xs:element name="document">
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element name="asset">
          <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
              <xs:element name="attribute" maxOccurs="unbounded" minOccurs="0">
                <xs:complexType>
                  <xs:sequence>
                    <xs:element name="string" minOccurs="0">
                      <xs:complexType>
                        <xs:simpleContent>
                          <xs:extension base="xs:string">
                            <xs:attribute type="xs:string" name="value" use="optional"/>
                          </xs:extension>
                        </xs:simpleContent>
                      </xs:complexType>
                    </xs:element>
                    <xs:element name="date" minOccurs="0">
                      <xs:complexType>
                        <xs:simpleContent>
                          <xs:extension base="xs:string">
                            <xs:attribute type="xs:string" name="value" use="optional"/>
                          </xs:extension>
                        </xs:simpleContent>
                      </xs:complexType>
                    </xs:element>
                    <xs:element name="array" minOccurs="0">
                      <xs:complexType>
                        <xs:sequence>
                          <xs:element name="struct"  maxOccurs="unbounded" minOccurs="0">
                            <xs:complexType>
                              <xs:sequence>
                                <xs:element name="field" maxOccurs="unbounded" minOccurs="0">
                                  <xs:complexType>
                                    <xs:sequence>
                                      <xs:element name="integer" minOccurs="0">
                                        <xs:complexType>
                                          <xs:simpleContent>
                                            <xs:extension base="xs:string">
                                              <xs:attribute type="xs:byte" name="value"/>
                                            </xs:extension>
                                          </xs:simpleContent>
                                        </xs:complexType>
                                      </xs:element>
                                      <xs:element name="assetreference" minOccurs="0">
                                        <xs:complexType>
                                          <xs:simpleContent>
                                            <xs:extension base="xs:string">
                                              <xs:attribute type="xs:string" name="type"/>
                                              <xs:attribute type="xs:long" name="value"/>
                                            </xs:extension>
                                          </xs:simpleContent>
                                        </xs:complexType>
                                      </xs:element>
                                    </xs:sequence>
                                    <xs:attribute type="xs:string" name="name" use="optional"/>
                                  </xs:complexType>
                                </xs:element>
                              </xs:sequence>
                            </xs:complexType>
                          </xs:element>
                          <xs:element name="integer" minOccurs="0">
                            <xs:complexType>
                              <xs:simpleContent>
                                <xs:extension base="xs:string">
                                  <xs:attribute type="xs:long" name="value"/>
                                </xs:extension>
                              </xs:simpleContent>
                            </xs:complexType>
                          </xs:element>
                        </xs:sequence>
                      </xs:complexType>
                    </xs:element>
                    <xs:element name="file" minOccurs="0">
                      <xs:complexType>
                        <xs:simpleContent>
                          <xs:extension base="xs:string">
                            <xs:attribute type="xs:string" name="name" use="optional"/>
                          </xs:extension>
                        </xs:simpleContent>
                      </xs:complexType>
                    </xs:element>
                    <xs:element name="integer" minOccurs="0">
                      <xs:complexType>
                        <xs:simpleContent>
                          <xs:extension base="xs:string">
                            <xs:attribute type="xs:short" name="value"/>
                          </xs:extension>
                        </xs:simpleContent>
                      </xs:complexType>
                    </xs:element>
                  </xs:sequence>
                  <xs:attribute type="xs:string" name="name" use="optional"/>
                </xs:complexType>
              </xs:element>
            </xs:sequence>
            <xs:attribute type="xs:long" name="id"/>
            <xs:attribute type="xs:string" name="type"/>
          </xs:complexType>
        </xs:element>
      </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

and below is the JAXB binding file which is working for above XSD:

```
<bindings xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jaxb"
          xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2000/10/XMLSchema-instance"
          xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
          version="2.1">
    <bindings schemaLocation= "../assetproduct.xsd" version="1.0">
        <!-- Customise the package name 
        <schemaBindings>
            <package name="com.example.schema"/>
        </schemaBindings> -->

        <!-- rename the value element -->
        <bindings node="//xs:element[@name='document']">
            <bindings node="//xs:element[@name='asset']">
                <bindings node="//xs:element[@name='attribute']">

                    <bindings node="//xs:element[@name='string']">
                        <bindings node=".//xs:attribute[@name='value']">
                            <property name="ValueAttribute"/>
                        </bindings>
                    </bindings>


                    <bindings node="//xs:element[@name='date']">
                        <bindings node=".//xs:attribute[@name='value']">
                            <property name="ValueAttribute"/>
                        </bindings>
                    </bindings>

                    <bindings node="//xs:element[@name='array']">

                        <bindings node=".//xs:element[@name='struct']">
                            <bindings node=".//xs:element[@name='field']">

                                <bindings node=".//xs:element[@name='integer']/xs:complexType">
                                    <bindings node=".//xs:attribute[@name='value']">
                                        <property name="ValueAttribute"/>
                                    </bindings>
                                </bindings>

                                <bindings node=".//xs:element[@name='assetreference']">
                                    <bindings node=".//xs:attribute[@name='value']">
                                        <property name="ValueAttribute"/>
                                    </bindings>
                                </bindings>

                            </bindings>
                        </bindings>

                    </bindings>

                    <bindings node=".//xs:element[@name='array']/xs:complexType/xs:sequence/xs:element[@name='integer']">
                            <bindings node=".//xs:attribute[@name='value']">
                                <property name="ValueAttribute"/>
                            </bindings>
                    </bindings>

                    <bindings node="//xs:element[@name='attribute']/xs:complexType/xs:sequence/xs:element[@name='integer']">
                        <bindings node=".//xs:attribute[@name='value']">
                            <property name="ValueAttribute"/>
                        </bindings>
                    </bindings>
                </bindings>
            </bindings>
          </bindings>
    </bindings>
</bindings>
```

Answer (score 0):

Firstly you need to see, which property or attribute you want to rename. Is it the property that is being used inside another property or is it the declaration of property you want to change.
In my case it is the declaration that I have to change-

```
<xs:attribute name="title" type="xlink:titleAttrType"/>
```

The property title is used inside group attribute as below-

```
  <xs:attributeGroup name="simpleAttrs">
  <xs:attribute ref="xlink:type" fixed="simple"/>
  <xs:attribute ref="xlink:href"/>
  <xs:attribute ref="xlink:role"/>
  <xs:attribute ref="xlink:arcrole"/>
  <xs:attribute ref="xlink:title"/>
  <xs:attribute ref="xlink:show"/>
  <xs:attribute ref="xlink:actuate"/>
  </xs:attributeGroup>
```

So I have written jaxb binding accordingly for a attribute declaration and not the binding of property used in attribute group simpleAttrs. After this name conflict is resolved from declaration itself references would be updated by itself.

```
 <jaxb:bindings schemaLocation="xlink/xlink.xsd" node="/xs:schema">
    <jaxb:bindings>
        <jaxb:nameXmlTransform>
            <jaxb:elementName suffix="Element"/>
        </jaxb:nameXmlTransform>
        <jaxb:bindings node="//xs:attribute[@type='xlink:titleAttrType'][@name='title']">
            <jaxb:property name="TitleAttr"/>
        </jaxb:bindings>
    </jaxb:bindings>
</jaxb:bindings>
```