# Setting hyperjaxb mapping to force implementation of external interface

Tags: java, maven, jpa, jaxb, hyperjaxb

I have an hyperjaxb xsd file and binding configuration. How can I force my generated classes to implement a custom interface declared in another artifact? I know I can make them extend another class by using

```
    <xjc:superClass name="com.sample.jpa.entities.BaseEntity"/>
```

But I need them to implement another interface also. How can I achieve that?

Comment: Check the inheritance plugin in JAXB2-Basics.

Comment: Can this be used in conjunction with hyperjaxb?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Disclaimer:** Author of [Hyperjaxb](https://github.com/highsource/hyperjaxb3) and [JAXB2-Basics](https://github.com/highsource/jaxb2-basics) here.

You can use the [Inheritance plugin](http://confluence.highsource.org/display/J2B/Inheritance+plugin) from [JAXB2-Basics](https://github.com/highsource/jaxb2-basics) together with [Hyperjaxb](https://github.com/highsource/hyperjaxb3). You can both extend a class or implement an interface. The plugin can also process generics so you can even do stuff like `<inheritance:implements>com.acme.foo.MyInterface&lt;com.acme.foo.SomeClass&gt;</inheritance:implements>`.

Short guide:

- Enable th plugin via `<arg>-Xinheritance</arg>` in your `pom.xml`. Something like:

  ```
      <plugin>
          <groupId>org.jvnet.hyperjaxb3</groupId>
          <artifactId>maven-hyperjaxb3-plugin</artifactId>
          <configuration>
              <!--result>mappingFiles</result-->
              <roundtripTestClassName>org.jvnet.hyperjaxb3.ejb.tests.cuone.RoundtripTest</roundtripTestClassName>
              <args>
                  <arg>-Xinheritance</arg>
              </args>
          </configuration>
      </plugin>
  ```

  JAXB2-Basics is a dependency if Hyperjaxb so you most probably won't need to do anything else here. See the [example](https://github.com/highsource/hyperjaxb3/blob/602378e16d38337d5279f5b190ee503525189e09/ejb/tests/cu-one/pom.xml#L40-L57) (for the annotate plugin but that does not matter).
- Customize your complex types with `inheritance:extends` or `inheritance:implements` customization elements. Example:

  ```
  <jaxb:bindings schemaLocation="schema.xsd" node="/xsd:schema">
      <jaxb:bindings node="xsd:complexType[@name='WillBeMadeCloneableType']">
          <inheritance:implements>java.lang.Cloneable</inheritance:implements>
      </jaxb:bindings>
  </jaxb:bindings>
  ```

That should be it.

Comment: Perfect! How can I make it globally? Apply the inheritance to all the types defined in my xsd?

Comment: @AlfredoA. Just apply to many nodes via XPath. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12043255/jaxb-bindingx-xml-results-in-too-many-target-nodes