# ModelMapper: mapping an xs:IDREF which is a List of JAXBElement of Object

Tags: jaxb, modelmapper, idref, jaxbelement

I am using ModelMapper (3.2.0) to map JAXB Beans to my domain beans.

The schema which is used to generate the JAXB Beans contains `xs:IDREF` elements, which are represented as `List<JAXBElement<Object>>` in the JAXB Bean.

But ModelMapper doesn't understand how to map the source bean to my target bean - rather it maps the unmapped source bean into the target. In other words, the `List<JAXBElement<Object>>` in the source - which is a `List<JAXBElement<Dokument>>` at runtime - ends up in the target as-is.

(The`xs:IDREF` is a feature of XML: one can refer to XML Elements elsewhere in the XML document by means of an XML id that is unique in the document.)

Excerpt of the xsd schema:

```
<xs:complexType name="IdentitaetUndAufenthaltsstatus">
  <xs:sequence>
     <xs:element name="ausweisart" type="xs:string"/>
     <xs:element name="aufenthaltsstatus" minOccurs="0" type="xeb:Aufenthaltsstatus"/>
     <xs:element name="dokumentIDReferenz"
                 minOccurs="0"
                 maxOccurs="unbounded"
                 type="xs:IDREF"/>
  </xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>
```

Here is the generated JAXB bean which matches the schema. Note the type of the attribute `dokumentIDReferenz`:

```
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlType(name = "IdentitaetUndAufenthaltsstatus", propOrder = {
    "ausweisart",
    "aufenthaltsstatus",
    "dokumentIDReferenz"
})
public class IdentitaetUndAufenthaltsstatus
    implements Serializable
{

    private final static long serialVersionUID = 100L;
    @XmlElement(required = true)
    @NotNull
    @Valid
    protected CodeAusweisart ausweisart;
    @Valid
    protected Aufenthaltsstatus aufenthaltsstatus;
    @XmlElementRef(name = "dokumentIDReferenz", namespace = "https://portalverbund.d-nrw.de/efa/XEinbuergerung/Version_1_4_0", type = JAXBElement.class, required = false)
    protected List<JAXBElement<Object>> dokumentIDReferenz;

    // ... getters and setters ...
}
```

What I would like in the target is the following:

```
public class IdentitaetUndAufenthaltsstatus {
    protected String ausweisart;
    protected Aufenthaltsstatus aufenthaltsstatus;
    protected List<DokumentDto>> dokumentIDReferenz;
    // ...
}
```

ModelMapper is unhappy with that:

```
1) Unmapped destination properties found in TypeMap[JAXBElement -> DokumentDto]:

    de.example.commons.xeinbuergerung.domain.DokumentDto.setDokumentnummer()
    de.example.commons.xeinbuergerung.domain.DokumentDto.setAktuelleVersion()
    de.example.commons.xeinbuergerung.domain.DokumentDto.setLetzteVersion()
    de.example.commons.xeinbuergerung.domain.DokumentDto.setDokumentID()
    de.example.commons.xeinbuergerung.domain.DokumentDto.setDokumentTyp()
      
de.example.commons.xeinbuergerung.domain.Dokument.setDokumentRepraesentation()
```

I am unable to tell ModelMapper how it should map a `JAXBElement<Dokument>` into a `DokumentDTO`.

If I rewrite my target bean so that it expects a `List<JAXBElement<DokumentDto>>`, ModelMapper does map the field, but it fills in the original `List<JAXBElement<Dokument>>` instead of `List<JAXBElement<Dokument>>`.

I have tried to apply a `Converter`, hoping I could use the ModelMapper engine to map inside the converter:

```
jaxbElementDokumentConverter = new Converter<JAXBElement<Dokument>,
            de.example.commons.xeinbuergerung.domain.DokumentDto>() {
            @Override
            public de.example.commons.xeinbuergerung.domain.DokumentDto convert(MappingContext<JAXBElement<Dokument>,
                de.example.commons.xeinbuergerung.domain.DokumentDto> context) {
                return context.getTypeMap().map(context.getSource());
            }
        };
```

But it gives me this weird error:

```
*** java.lang.instrument ASSERTION FAILED ***: "!errorOutstanding" with message transform method call failed at JPLISAgent.c line: 844
*** java.lang.instrument ASSERTION FAILED ***: "!errorOutstanding" with message transform method call failed at JPLISAgent.c line: 844
*** java.lang.instrument ASSERTION FAILED ***: "!errorOutstanding" with message transform method call failed at JPLISAgent.c line: 844
*** java.lang.instrument ASSERTION FAILED ***: "!errorOutstanding" with message transform method call failed at JPLISAgent.c line: 844
*** java.lang.instrument ASSERTION FAILED ***: "!errorOutstanding" with message transform method call failed at JPLISAgent.c line: 844
*** java.lang.instrument ASSERTION FAILED ***: "!errorOutstanding" with message transform method call failed at JPLISAgent.c line: 844
*** java.lang.instrument ASSERTION FAILED ***: "!errorOutstanding" with message transform method call failed at JPLISAgent.c line: 844
*** java.lang.instrument ASSERTION FAILED ***: "!errorOutstanding" with message transform method call failed at JPLISAgent.c line: 844
*** java.lang.instrument ASSERTION FAILED ***: "!errorOutstanding" with message transform method call failed at JPLISAgent.c line: 844
Disconnected from the target VM, address: '127.0.0.1:56236', transport: 'socket'

org.modelmapper.MappingException: ModelMapper mapping errors:

1 error

    at org.modelmapper.internal.Errors.throwMappingExceptionIfErrorsExist(Errors.java:386)
    at org.modelmapper.internal.MappingEngineImpl.map(MappingEngineImpl.java:80)
    at org.modelmapper.ModelMapper.mapInternal(ModelMapper.java:589)
    at org.modelmapper.ModelMapper.map(ModelMapper.java:422)
    at de.example.xeinbuergerung.v140.business.XEinbuergerungService.getVorgangTransportieren2010(XEinbuergerungService.java:102)
    at de.example.xeinbuergerung.v140.business.XEinbuergerungServiceTest.mapToEingangsnachrichtAndGetDigitalerEinbuergerungsAntrag(XEinbuergerungServiceTest.java:42)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:50)
    at org.junit<...>org.modelmapper.internal.MappingEngineImpl.typeMap(MappingEngineImpl.java:137)
    at org.modelmapper.internal.TypeMapImpl.map(TypeMapImpl.java:186)
    at de.example.xeinbuergerung.v140.mapper.XEinbuergerungModule$3.convert(XEinbuergerungModule.java:54)
    at de.example.xeinbuergerung.v140.mapper.XEinbuergerungModule$3.convert(XEinbuergerungModule.java:50)
    at org.modelmapper.internal.MappingEngineImpl.convert(MappingEngineImpl.java:306)
    at org.modelmapper.internal.MappingEngineImpl.typeMap(MappingEngineImpl.java:137)
    at org.modelmapper.internal.TypeMapImpl.map(TypeMapImpl.java:186)
    at de.example.xeinbuergerung.v140.mapper.XEinbuergerungModule$3.convert(XEinbuergerungModule.java:54)
    at de.example.xeinbuergerung.v140.mapper.XEinbuergerungModule$3.convert(XEinbuergerungModule.java:50)
    at org.modelmapper.internal.MappingEngineImpl.convert(MappingEngineImpl.java:306)
    at org.modelmapper.internal.MappingEngineImpl.typeMap(MappingEngineImpl.java:137)
```

I suppose ModelMapper fails to unwrap the `JAXBelement` automatically. But how to tell it to call `JAXBElement.getValue()` and then map the result?

Comment: As a workaround, instead of mapping whole objects by ID reference, I let JAXB map the referenced id instead of the objects. Since my schema has many such references, I also have to apply multiple='true' https://stackoverflow.com/a/13768053/743507. This also solved another problem with a different id reference which somehow seemed to "pollute" ModelMapper's typemap and caused a difficult to solve mapping exception.